# Page data not reloading when routing back using userouter in client component in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I am using app router in nextjs, and have a page that lists all the companies (server component) in the route /select-company

```
//fetch data from database..this is route /select-company (server component)

export default async function CompanyPage() {
  const session = await getServerSession(options);
  const user_id = session?.user?.user_id; 
  const data: Company[] = await fetchCompanies(user_id); //simple database query..works fine
    
  return (
    <main>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
//this displays data. And has a Create Company button that routes to /create-company page
        <CompanyList data={data} />
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  )
}
```

this is my database query component (server side) where i am adding noStore to prevent data cache

```
export async function fetchCompanies(user_id: User['user_id']){
    // Dont cache data
    noStore();
    
    const client = await pool.connect();

    try {
   const data = await client.query(`SELECT a.company_id, b.company_alias, b.company_name FROM company_user as a
            LEFT JOIN company as b on a.company_id = b.company_id WHERE a.user_id = $1`, [user_id])

        if(data.rowCount === 0) throw new Error("No company found")
        return data.rows;
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error(error.message);
      throw new Error(error.message);
    } finally {
    client.release();
    }
}
```

this is the create-company page which is a client component

```
// client component
const CreateCompanyPage = () => {
    const [err, setErr] = useState('')
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)
    const router = useRouter();
    const { data: session, status } = useSession()
  
    const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
        setErr('')

        try {
            const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/company", 
                                 JSON.stringify({company_alias: form.get('alias'), company_name: form.get('name'), user_id: session?.user.user_id})
                                )
            setSuccess(true)
            
            setTimeout(() => {
               router.push("/select-company")
                
            }, 500);
        } catch(error: any) {
           setErr(error.response.data.message)
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center p-5 h-screen gap-5">
            {success 
                ? <p>"Company created sucessfully. Transferring to app"</p> 
                : <>
                    <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">Create Company</h1>
                    <form className="flex flex-col gap-5" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <input required type='text' className="p-3 text-base rounded-md border-2 border-solid w-72" placeholder='Company Alias (no spaces)' name='alias' />
                        <input required type='text' className="p-3 text-base rounded-md border-2 border-solid w-72" placeholder='Company Full Name' name='name' />
                        <CreateButton />
                    </form>
                    
                    {err && <p className="text-red-600 text-center text-sm">{err}</p>}
                    {/* {success && <p className="text-blue-600 text-center text-sm">{success}</p>} */}
                </>
            }       
        </main>
        
    )
}

const CreateButton = () => {
    const {pending} = useFormStatus();
    
    return <button className={buttonVariants({variant:"blue", size:"lg"})} disabled={pending}>Create</button>
}

export default CreateCompanyPage
```

Everything works fine except that when a company is created and user is redirected back to /select-company using router.push method, it is not reloading the data and shows the previous data. I have to manually refresh the page to fetch the latest data.

I have tried adding `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"` to the /select-company route but that doesnt work also.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I hope CompanyList is a client component,try to send user_id to CompanyList component as a prop and put all the fetching codes in this component and use "useEffect"

Comment: Yeah but I want to keep all data fetching at server as much as possible.

Comment: what has worked is adding "router.refresh()" before "router.push"